# Bad Integrated Windows Authentication credentials in Spring (it seems to get wrong token through IE)

Tags: spring, spring-security, kerberos, windows-authentication, spnego

I have set an infrastructure with AD + Kerberos + Spring (Security + Kerberos) and there is an issue related to automatically log into the application with IWA:

1. If Internet Explorer tries to log in automatically (using current logged  user + password data), it generates a strange token and therefore, it fails.

   Token:
   Try to validate Kerberos Token
   Negotiate Header was invalid: Negotiate YIGABgYrBgEFBQKgdjB0oDAwLgYKKwYBBAGCNwICCgYJKoZIgvcSAQICBgkqhkiG9xIBAgIGCisGAQQBgjcCAh6iQAQ+TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl7II4ggACAA2AAAADgAOACgAAAAKAGNFAAAAD1NDSU5GSU5JVFk0Nzk5S0VSQkVST1M=
2. After the first attempt, it prompts the Windows user/password credentials login. Then, after introducing the right user (existing one in AD), it succeeds at the login.

   The token is completely different, a valid one:
   Negotiate 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

Why is it not working from the beginning? Right after opening the browser (IE), it seems there is no Kerberos/AD configuration issue, because the second case, it works.

I have the infrastructure in a Windows Server 2019 and I am logged into the server to perform the tests. I'm not sure if it would affect the testing itself. (maybe this does not make sense at all)

Comment: Are you logged in as a _local_ user on the machine? The first message is IE trying to speak NTLM.